# What is the Productivity way in Mysql to use them in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, function, methods

as SQL server support .net well because both come from MSFT. but mostly i use MySQL whenever i need to use a database in application.

for DAL i write Queries in SQL put them in function written in c# and for execution i use connector [for C#.net Mysql.data dll]

i hear that SQL server many way to make data transaction between database and code. i am using the same way from a long time so i want to know are their any other method exist in Mysql who are best to working with Mysql.

My means doing something better not only write queries and put them in function. Well how much way i can use Mysql for doing data-transaction.

i want to know how i can improve Everything who relate to My Mysql data and way to handle queries in code behind c#.

i need a guide who can give me a detailed about Everything about Mysql and give the guideline and news like ASP.NET have for ASP.net

Are their any website for Mysql who continuesly update.

Comment: I can hardly understand what you're asking, but you may want to look at [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://www.nhforge.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stored procedures, and views when possible.